# OffsetDateTime Parse DateTimeParseException

Tags: java, kotlin, java-8

I am converting the date "2019-12-17T06:50:00.000Z" to OffsetDateTime like

```
OffsetDateTime.parse("2019-12-17T06:50:00.000Z").
```

I am getting error as

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '[{"date":"2019-12-17T02:10:00.000Z"}]' could not be parsed at index 0 at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949).

How can parse this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to parse the JSON `[{"date":"2019-12-17T02:10:00.000Z"}]` with `OffsetDateTime` however you should only parse the `date` field from the JSON. Take a look at [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2591098/1602555) question to understand how to extract a field from JSON.

If this is a very simple case where you always have the same input format you can use [`String.substring()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int))

```
String json = "[{\"date\":\"2019-12-17T02:10:00.000Z\"}]";
String value = json.substring(10, 34);
OffsetDateTime dt = OffsetDateTime.parse(value);
System.out.println(dt); // 2019-12-17T02:10Z
```

Comment: Hi Karol, I have scenario where i am getting an instant converted to OffsetDateTime, then i need to do like ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(Instant.parse(offsetDateTime), Instant.now()) It give me DateTimeParseException in case of 2021-07-15T05:27Z
as if it was 2021-07-15T05:27:00Z . it would work fine